# Cartesian arrow over an iso is an iso

Tags: category-theory

Let $p:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{B}$ be a fibration. I'm working on showing that a Cartesian arrow $f:X\to Y$ over an isomorphism is also an isomorphism.  I see how to get a right inverse $u:Y\to X$ as below [image]

but I'm having difficulty showing that $u$ is also a left inverse. Any assistance is appreciated.

---

EDIT: I was never quite able to fully work out the proof suggestion in the answer below, but it seems correct so I'm leaving it accepted.  For anyone who's curious, I ended up proving it as follows:

We have that $$f\circ 1_X=f=1_Y\circ f=f\circ u\circ f$$ and there is only one unique arrow $n:X\to X$ above $1_{p(X)}$ such that $f\circ n=f$ since $f$ is Cartesian, but $1_X:X\to X$ and $u\circ f:X\to X$ are both above $1_{p(X)}$ and satisfy this identity so $n=1_X=u\circ f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go at it in a different direction. Define $u$ as a Cartesian lift of $p(f)^{-1}$. Now since Cartesian morphism are closed under composition you still know $fu$ is an identity, but you also know $u$ is Cartesian. You can then show just as you have for $f$ that $u$ has a right inverse, and from $fu=1_Y$ and $uh=1_X$ we get $f=fuh=h$, so $f=u^{-1}$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I follow everything except the fact that $fu$ is an identity. How does this follow from the fact that Cartesian maps are closed under composition?  I see how that yields that $fu$ is Cartesian and thusly isomorphic to the identity in a slice category, but how do we get that $fu$ is an identity on the nose? Any nontrivial automorphism of an object $X$ is isomorphic to the identity on $X$ in the slice category at $X$.

Comment: @AlecRhea Sure, good point, but even if $fu$ is just some isomorphism, that still establishes that $u$ has a left inverse. Continuing the argument, $uh$ being an iso gives that $u$ has a right inverse, so $u$ is iso and thus so is $f$.

Comment: Ah, good point, thank you.

Comment: While trying to write down the details of this stuff I realized I still don't see how $fu$ is an isomorphism; any arrow $f:X\to X$ with a right inverse will be isomorphic to the identity on $X$ in the slice category at $X$. For a left inverse, we need it to be isomorphic in the coslice category as well.

Comment: Ah, but if the right inverse is also isomorphic to the identity in the slice category that gives a left inverse, and this is essentially your argument. Thank you.